# Vectorization and Optimization of function in Python

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization

I am fairly new to python and trying to transfer some code from matlab to python. I am trying to optimize a function in python using fmin_bfgs. I always try to vectorize the code when possible, but I ran into the following problem that I can't figure out. Here is a test example.

```
from pylab import *
from scipy.optimize import fmin_bfgs


## Create some linear data
L=linspace(0,10,100).reshape(100,1)
n=L.shape[0]
M=2*L+5
L=hstack((ones((n,1)),L))

m=L.shape[0]

## Define sum of squared errors as non-vectorized and vectorized
def Cost(theta,X,Y):
    return 1.0/(2.0*m)*sum((theta[0]+theta[1]*X[:,1:2]-Y)**2)

def CostVec(theta,X,Y):
    err=X.dot(theta)-Y
    resid=err**2
    return 1.0/(2.0*m)*sum(resid) 

## Initialize the theta
theta=array([[0.0], [0.0]])

## Run the minimization on the two functions
print fmin_bfgs(Cost, x0=theta,args=(L,M))
print fmin_bfgs(CostVec, x0=theta,args=(L,M))
```

The first answer, with the unvectorized function, gives the correct answer which is just the vector [5, 2]. But, the the second answer, using the vectorizied form of the cost function returns roughly [15,0]. I have figured out the 15 doesn't appear from nowhere as it is 2 times the mean of the data plus the intercept, i.e., $2\times 5+5$. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to ensure that `(theta[0]+theta[1]*X[:,1:2]-Y)**2` (from the first approach) is indeed equivalent to `resid` in the second approach.  This is easily checked with some print statements.

Comment: This was the first thing that I tried to do and everything checked out. I was able to get the correct answer with both functions using a gradient descent code that I wrote.

Comment: When I print the computed value inside the functions before it's returned, for some reason when running fmin_bfgs the values computed by CostVec are 10 times that computed by Cost.  But explicitly calling them gives the same result.  Something strange happens with CostVec when running through fmin_bfgs.

Comment: That is exactly what I got when I ran some print statements. It is nice to know that I am not crazy. Is this a bug with fmin_bfgs? It also gave the same result when I ran fmin.